# If my class implements an interface, can't ReSharper figure that out and link the 2?

Tags: c#, oop, interface, resharper

If I have a interface IUser and a class that implements IUser:

```
public class User : IUSer
```

and both files are in different folders, can't ReSharper figure this out and link the two if I need to push down a method to the interface and vice versa?

Comment: Not sure about Resharper but DevExpress CodeRush handles this fine. I would figure that resharper did as well.

Answer (score 4):

If I create a class User and an interface IUser, R# allows me to refactor "Pull member up" and move a method from the class to the interface.

I can use "Push member down" to move code from the interface to the implementation again.

For my simple testcase (simple interface with one property, one class that implements it) this works as expected and as I'd use it. What's missing?